# How to calculate Upper/Low sums of an arbitrary partition?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

If I'm given a function $f$ that is continuous on $[a,b]$ and asked to find the Upper sum $U(f,P)$ and Lower sum $L(f,P)$ where $P$ is an arbitrary partition of of a given interval $I$; $P$ = $\{x_i\}_{i=0}^n$.

> $$U(f,P) = \sum_{i=1}^n M_i (x_i - x_{i-1}) \; \text{where} \; M_i = \sup\{f(x):p_0 ,..., p_{i-1}\}$$
>   $$L(f,P) = \sum_{i=1}^n m_i (x_i - x_{i-1}) \; \text{where} \; m_i = \inf\{f(x):p_0 ,..., p_{i-1}\}$$

How would I calculate the upper/lower sums of arbitrary partition $P$ = $\{x_i\}_{i=0}^n$ since I do not know my $n$ value?

If the function is is either increasing or decreasing over $I$, would I just choose the right or left endpoint of $I$ as my $M_i$ or $m_i$ value and simplify $(x_i - x_{i-1})$ to $(b-a)$?

If my function isn't either increasing or decreasing over $I$, how would I calculate my sums with no given partition?

Comment: What is the context of this question? Usually you do not want to compute the sums directly. You are correct that for monotonous function you pick left of right endpoint.

Comment: I'm being asked to calculate the upper and lower sums of a couple of given functions, over a given interval and for some, the partitions have been given and for others, it just says P is an arbitrary partition. However, the functions in which P is not defined, the functions are monotone over I, so I was just wondering what I was to do if the function was not monotone and I was told to calculate the Upper/Lower sums and P was not specified.

Comment: That seems a bit strange to me. It might be possible that the sums actually do not depend on the partitioning, like for example for [Dirichlet function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html).